# How do I call this method only after the user has actually stopped panning or zooming?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;

function initialize()
{
    /* ... */

    google.maps.event.addListener(map,'idle',function()
    {
        /* do something here */
    });
}
</script>

<body onload="initialize()"> 
    <div id="map_canvas"></div> 
</body>
```

How can I make sure the stuff within `google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function()` is **not triggered** right after the page is done loading?

I want it to be triggered **only after** the user has actually stopped panning or zooming.

I also tried moving it outside the `initialize` function, but that of course didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the idle listener after a dragstart event has been fired

```
var map;

function initialize(){

    /* ... */

    google.maps.addListenerOnce(map, "dragstart",function(event){
        google.maps.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function(event2){
            /* ... */
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I just had it to change to `google.maps.event.addListenerOnce`. And thanks a lot, worked beautifully! :)