# gmaps.js using native Google Maps API v3 functions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I load my google maps with gmaps.js, which makes it easier to work with. The problem is some of the native functions aren't available, specifically I need `addListenerOnce`

http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/

I load my map like this:

```
searchmap = new GMaps({
     div: '#searchmap',
     lat: '40.7142691000',
     lng: '-74.0059729000',
});
```

I can add a event listener like this:

```
searchmap.addListener('idle', function() {
     //do something here
});
```

However I can't add the native `addListenerOnce`, so I assumed I could do this (which does not work):

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(searchmap, 'idle', function(){
     //do something
});
```

So any idea how I can use the `addListenerOnce`? (Clearly I am a JS novice... a lot of poking around in the github repo didn't help)

Comment: What is the error you get with the code that doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't show any errors, just doesn't see the event

Comment: Looking a bit closer I think the problem is that "idle" isn't an event, at least not one that I'm familiar with. Are you trying to detect when the user hasn't done something for a period of time?

Comment: It is an event. I don't plan to use that specific event though, just was an example. I need to use the addListenerOnce though. Events: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Comment: I stand corrected,though still not sure what the issue is. You might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867232/how-do-i-call-this-method-only-after-the-user-has-actually-stopped-panning-or-zo

Comment: Yeah he is suggesting using the addListenerOnce function, but can't get that to work. Thanks though

Comment: I would think without an error either the code isn't executing or the event isn't firing. You've tried an `alert` before and after you add the listener? A different event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the listener to the native google.maps.Map object:

http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/documentation.html#GMaps-map

This should work:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(searchmap.map, 'idle', function(){
   //do something
});
```

Comment: Yeah this is it, I knew I was missing something small. What does adding `map` to the end of my initiated gmaps `searchmap` do?

Comment: It references the .map property of the GMaps object (which is the native Google Maps Javascript API v3 (google.maps.Map) object.